# Half-duplex RS485 communication - synchronization issue on Raspberry PI

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, serial-port, rs485, termios

I am trying to connect devices via RS485 with use of MAX485. I have master-slave architecture with half-duplex communication. I made a successful test with a few Arduinos (no issues at speed 500000kbaud). I am able to have 2 ways communication between Raspberry PI and Arduino.

Raspberry PI is connected with MAX485 board via UART pins and 1 GPIO (4) for switching between transmitting and receiving.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a clean solution for synchronization when Raspberry PI should switch from transmitting to receiving. I tried use tcdrain() but it waits way too long (in below example it is 20 ms while the transfer is finished in less than 200us).

I was able to have request-response behavior by hacking with spin loops when waiting for data to be send and received but for sure it is not the most robust approach:

```
const int gpioPin = 4;
unsigned char buffer[2] = { '1', '2' };
struct timeval tv1, tv2;
unsigned long time_in_micros1, time_in_micros2;
struct termios options;
int fd;

// open serial
fd = open("/dev/serial0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1) {
  return(-1);
}

// set tty options
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
options.c_cflag = CREAD | CLOCAL | CS8 | CRTSCTS;
options.c_iflag = 0;
options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = 0;
cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &options);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

// Start of transmitting / end of receiving
GPIO_SET = 1<<4;

// Get start transmission time
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
time_in_micros1 = 1000000 * tv1.tv_sec + tv1.tv_usec;

// Send bytes
const int n = write(fd, buffer, 2);
if (n < 0) {
  return -1;
}

// Wait for data to be sent
do {
  gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
  time_in_micros2 = 1000000 * tv2.tv_sec + tv2.tv_usec;
} while (time_in_micros2 - time_in_micros1 <= 200); // value find empirically, time for transfering 2 bytes was not enough

//tcdrain(fd); /* THIS WAITS TOO LONG! */

// End of transmitting / start receiving
GPIO_CLR = 1<<4;

// Read response
int count = 0;
while (count < 2) {
  unsigned char val;
  int bytes = read(fd, &val, 1);
  if (bytes > 0) {
    printf("%d\n", val);
    count += bytes;
  } else if (bytes < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I could improve that code so that I now when to switch between transmitting and receiving?

Comment: You're trying to control hardware from userspace, but that should be performed either in the device driver or (automatically) by hardware.  Userspace is too many layers distant to be synchronized with hardware operations. BTW your termios configuration is not reliable.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)

Comment: OT: regarding: `tcgetattr(fd, &options);
...
tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &options);`   You will want to restore the I/O configuration to its' default value, so should copy the `options` to a 'backup_options' before modifying the fields, so that before exiting the program can have: `tcsetattr( fd, TCSADRAIN, back_options );`

Comment: regarding: the call to `read()` and the call to `write()` those functions return a `ssize_t`, not an `int`.   When you enable the warnings when compiling, then your compiler would have told you about this problem

Comment: OT: rather than messing with the individual fields of `options`, suggest using `cfmakeraw()`

Comment: regarding: `do {
  gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
  time_in_micros2 = 1000000 * tv2.tv_sec + tv2.tv_usec;
} while (time_in_micros2 - time_in_micros1 <= 200);`  This wastes time.  Suggest: `tcdrain( fd ); gettimeofday( &tv2, NULL );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d\n", val);`   This is a major time waster.  Suggest a buffer and input the characters into the buffer.  Then when the inputting of characters is complete, then echo the characters to the terminal.

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for these hints. Good point with setting back_options when exiting the program. I love cfmakeraw - it is great to have something "default". Regarding the other things, those were just for test.